# tabpanel within shiny app in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have been asked to do a simple shiny app. I have the following code for it:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(title = "Central Limit Theorem",
             sliderInput(inputId = "num", label = "Choose a sample size",
                         value = 5, min = 1, max = 50),
              plotOutput(outputId = "hist")
    )
    ,
      tabPanel(title = "BMI prediction",
               pageWithSidebar(
               # Application title
               headerPanel("BMI prediction"),

               sidebarPanel(
                 numericInput('wt', 'Weight in Pounds', 90, min = 50, max = 200),
                 submitButton('Submit'),
                 numericInput('ht', 'Height in Inches', 60, min = 50, max = 85),
                 submitButton('Submit')
                ),
               mainPanel(
                 h3('Results of prediction'),
                 h4('Your weight is'),
                 verbatimTextOutput("inputValue1"),
                 h4('Your height is'),
                 verbatimTextOutput("inputValue2"),
                 h4('Which resulted in a BMI of '),
                 verbatimTextOutput("prediction")

               )
              )

        )

        )
      )  
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    par(mfrow = c(1,2))
    r <- 10000
    samp <- matrix(rexp(n=(input$num)*r, rate = 2), nrow = r)
    sample.means <- apply(samp,1,mean) 
    hist(sample.means,col="purple", main="Sampling Distribution of the Sample Mean", 
         xlab = "Sample Mean")
    qqnorm(sample.means, col = "purple")
  })
   bmi_calc <- function(weight, height) (weight/height^2)*703
   output$inputValue1 <- renderPrint({input$wt})
   output$inputValue2 <- renderPrint({input$ht})
   output$prediction <- renderPrint({bmi_calc(input$wt, input$ht)})
   } 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Due to some reason, the histograms in the first tab does not respond to the slider. If I don't include the second tab, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the two `submitButton`s; if you click either button on the second tab and go back to the first, it will have updated. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to specify which inputs a `submitButton` updates (currently both work for all three inputs, so the two on the second tab are redundant). There are, though, a few alternatives:

- Put a `submitButton` on each tab, which will harmlessly (unless one is really resource-intense) update all inputs.
- Put a `submitButton` outside of the `tabsetPanel`, so one button works updates all three inputs.
- Use an `actionButton` to update whatever values you like explicitly. This approach gives you much finer control over exactly what gets updated when, but comes at the cost of being more work to code. If you have a widget that requires a lot of resources that you don't want to over-update, this is the best option.
- Get rid of all the buttons, so everything updates instantaneously. In this example, this is my preference, as the operations performed are not resource-intensive and it results in a more responsive user experience.

Comment: Awesome! I have included an update button in each tab, so that the user gets the feeling of having control over the results in each tab separately, which I like better. Thanks.